# correct image orientation from camera

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

I took a few pictures with the camera on my Galaxy S, and when I viewed them on the PC (via USB) they all were on their side - obviously the camera has taken them in portrait orientation, but why would the images appear sideways when copied to the PC? Is it possible to make them save in the orientation they were taken - ie portrait if taken as portrait shots, landscape if taken when the phone is held 'horizontally'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some systems think of different ways to use the exif information. There are several possiblities, but for the motorola milestone (droid in the US) it was that the picture got a "rotated" mark in the EXIF, but it didn't get the height/width set correctly

(example: lets say you have a hxw = 3x4 camera. If you take a landscape shot, you'll get the normal hxw= 3x4 sized shot, and everything is fine. If you take a portrait shot, you STILL get the hxw = 3x4 (but you would want to see hxw = 4x3), and an extra mark that says "this shot was rotated). Some programs could work with this (twitpic for instance), but some coudn't.

Now you might face the same issue. I would look into your shots, and check what the exif says. If the exif has one of these issues, you might need to change (possibly use some sort of automatic process) the exif. Also, another viewer might help here.

Comment: cheers. my viewer is Windows - explorer and image viewer. The fix is easy - open and rotate them, but still annoying.

Comment: You might want to watch out with that. I don't know if it differs between windows-versions, but the windows image-viewer does not always do "lossless" rotation: that means you are loosing quality because it is re-saving them and adding another 'layer' of JPG-compression. Consider using another tool for that, one that supports lossless-rotation